# can be value of attribute which is a key of composite key?

Tags: database, primary-key

I have dataset, in that there is country column and province column. Every record is not fill in province column. I want to use these two attributes as a composite key. Can I use as the composite key ?

Comment: All columns of a primary key are implicitly `NOT NULL`. So no, you can't use a column that allows NULLs as part of a primary key (assuming a relational database)